# pip + virtualenv: corrupted state

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, ipython, virtualenvwrapper

This looks like a corrupted state *somewhere*.

First, within a virtualenv, `pip freeze` reports that ipython is installed

```
% workon myvenv
(myvenv)% pip freeze | grep ipython
ipython==0.12.1
```

...but the `ipython` seen from within the virtualenv is *not* the one installed under the virtualenv:

```
(myvenv)% which ipython
/usr/bin/ipython
```

Indeed, if one tries to "uninstall" the copy of ipython installed under the virtualenv, pip refuses to so:

```
(myvenv)% pip uninstall ipython
Not uninstalling ipython at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /home/yt/.virtualenvs/myvenv
```

It will also refuse to install a new copy:

```
(myvenv)% pip install ipython
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

BTW, the copies of `pip` and `python` seen within the virtualenv are

```
(myvenv)% which pip
/home/yt/.virtualenvs/myvenv/bin/pip
(myvenv)% which python
/home/yt/.virtualenvs/myvenv/bin/python
```

Clearly, some state is corrupted here, and I'd like to figure out which.  I stress that I'm primarily interested in *first*, figuring out what is wrong, and only *second*, fixing it.  IOW, I'm interested in *troubleshooting* the problem, and *not* interested in "fixing" the problem by blind trial-and-error.  In my experience, the "fixes" produced through such blind muddling are only apparent, and in fact often make the underlying tangle only worse.

My immediate questions are:

1. why is `pip` looking at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` even though a virtualenv is active?
2. why does `pip freeze` show `ipython==0.12.1`, even though there's no `ipython` under the virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

Virtualenvs can either be created with or without 'system site packages'. I.e. you can choose whether you want to be able to see things installed system-wide when you're in the virtualenv. You must have created the virtualenv so it can see other packages. This explains both your qustions 1 and 2 - pip sees your system installation of IPython.

If you install something into the virtualenv, it will always use that before the system-wide copy. So you can install the latest version of IPython into the virtualenv by running:

```
pip install --upgrade ipython
```

Comment: Thanks.  "...You must have created the virtualenv so it can see other packages."  Would you happen to know where this configuration setting stored?

Comment: When you make the virtualenv, you can use the flags `--system-site-packages` or `--no-site-packages`. The default used to allow system site packages, it changed to exclude them about a year ago, I think.

Comment: there is also an `--ignore-installed` flag, which lets you install new packages again, without upgrading (useful for doing a `--user` or venv install, when another version is already installed system-wide that you don't want to touch).